# React re-rendering entire map every time one child updates

Tags: javascript, forms, reactjs

**Reworded:**

I have an array of FormElements. Each time one of them changes, I send the update to the parent Form. This form updates a state of formData.

The problem is that the map in the Form re-renders all of the children. What I need, is it to only render the one updated FormElement.

This causes a performance issue, espcially for dropdowns, where they have to get all the possible values from a database upon mounting.

There's a lot of code, so I'll try and put relavent stuff below:

**Form page:**

```
  handleFormElementChange(id, value) {
    var frm = this.state.formData;
    var index=-1;
    for(var i=0;i<frm.length;i++) {
      if(frm[i].id==id) {
        index=i;
        break;
      }
    }
    frm[index].value = value;
    this.setState({formData: frm, selectedElementId: id});
  }
```

*render:* (this is the problem, re-rendering all children)

```
const FormElements = ({formFields}) => (<div> {
  formFields.map(formField => (<FormElement name={formField.name} key={(formField.id != undefined) ? formField.id : "1"} editable={formField.editable} selected={this.state.selectedElementId} value={formField.value} id={formField.id} type={formField.fieldType} handleChange={this.handleFormElementChange.bind(this)}/>)
)} </div>);
```

**FormElement page:**

```
componentWillMount() {
    if(this.props.type == this.state.fieldTypesEnum.DROPDOWN) {
       var self = this;
        this.getDropdownVals(this.props.id, function(callback) {
          self.setState({
            dropdownVals: callback
          });
        });
    }
  }

  onChange(e) {
      this.props.handleChange(e.target.id, e.target.value);
  }
```

*render:*

```
 if(this.props.type == this.state.fieldTypesEnum.DROPDOWN) {
      var self = this;
      var MakeItem = function(item) {
        return <option key={(item.ID != undefined) ? item.ID : "1"} value={item.ID}>{item.value}</option>;
      };
      let data = this.state.dropdownVals;
      return (<div  class="form-group">
                <label  for={this.props.id}>{this.props.name}:</label>
                <select name={this.props.id} type={this.props.type} maxLength="20" class="form-control" disabled={!this.props.editable} id={this.props.id} value={this.state.isChecked} onChange={this.onChange} ref={(input) => { this.nameInput = input; }}>
                    {data.map(MakeItem)}
                </select>
```

Comment: the `debounce` method might be applicable here, if you don't want your handleChange method to fire so quickly. Here's a [reference](https://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-throttling-and-debouncing/)

Comment: Interesting! It's still not ideal because the drop downs flash and repopulate every time a field is changed

Comment: Is your method that pulls data from the database contingent upon the value of the form or are they both separate?

Comment: It uses the form field id if that's what you're asking

Answer (score 0):

1) You should probably call your database request at `componentDidMount` since componentWillMount doesn't have access to the dom just yet.

2) You could potentially use `componentWillUpdate` so you can check if you're getting valid data coming from the form, and/or stop the component from re-rendering based on certain cases.

Answer (score 0):

If the key of FormElement is the id that doesn't change, the element should not be unmounted and mounted again when the parent reloads. Are you sure the componentWillMount method is called every time you type in a field?

If FormElement is re-mounted every time you type, the content you have typed would be gone too.

Comment: Fair point. I might need to post more code but essentially the Formelement updates a state called formData in the parent Form, and the form then uses that to populate an array of FormElements

Comment: I think I know why the content of form field is not gone when re-mounted. The value is managed by the state of the parent and passed to the child as a prop. So you probably want to do the same for all the dropdown values. Namely, save all the dropdown values in the parent's state just like formData.id and formData.value. Then in the componentWillMount method of the child, check the dropdown values (e.g. formData.dropdownValues) that is passed from the parent. Make the api call only when formData.dropdownValues is empty or need to be updated.

Answer (score 0):

Is the number of FormElements dynamic? If not I suggest having a separate state for each of the FormElements in parent. Then you only need to refresh the element that has changed.

A better way is to use redux-form to manage the form states in redux store. Each FormElement subscribes to it's own state in the store so redux only refreshes the one that needs to be changed.